# shutdown wpf while messagebox open

Tags: c#, wpf

I try to automatically shut down an wpf application at midnight with:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Normal);
```

This works very well in general, but when there is a message box opening waiting for user response, the application fails to shutdown. Is there a way to shut down the application regardless of the opening messagebox?

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and report it to you. It is kind of odd because I believe I have being using Application.Current.Shutdown() and then for some reason that I do not remember, I changed to Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Normal).

Comment: Application.Current.Shutdown() works great. I did not know why I change it to Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(). I will study in detail the differences between these shutdown mechanisms. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WPF Applications use

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use Environment.Exit (immediately exits...very naughty to do on a GUI app) or find the MessageBox window and send them a close message, or hook the creation of any native MessageBox Dialogs (...i.e. track the Window handle, so you can then close them).

- [Close C# Console Application after MessageBox click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622069/close-c-sharp-console-application-after-messagebox-click)
- [Force to close MessageBox programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7926107/force-close-of-messagebox)
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/d3f89686-e4d0-4bb1-9052-31abef2a9d2a/
- [Closing Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146080/c-sharp-closing-applications)
- [Right way to close WPF GUI application: GetCurrentProcess().Kill(), Environment.Exit(0) or this.Shutdown()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880836/right-way-to-close-wpf-gui-application-getcurrentprocess-kill-environment)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188920.aspx

And a very very naughty way:

Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill()

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Environment.Exit(0) seems to work for Consoles and Application.Exit works for WinForm application. Kill the application will make the problem complicit here either because there is a lot of automatic invoked work to do before the shutting down. I will first check Application.Current.Shutdown(), if it does not work, I will try to Force Close of MessageBox as you suggested. Thanks.