# How to shutdown a WPF application if an exception occurs?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [shutdown wpf while messagebox open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828826/shutdown-wpf-while-messagebox-open)

I currently have code like this, but the problem is that even after I show the error in a `MessageBox` provided by `NLog`, I want to shut down the app, so the user can fix the problem, but the app continues after they click OK in the message box.

```
private void Load(string fileName)
    {
        try
        {
            var environments = GetEnvironments(fileName); 
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex.StackTrace);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828826/shutdown-wpf-while-messagebox-open

Answer (score 5):

The exception has been handled so will not bubble up.

You have several options:

- Rethrow the exception after logging, causing the exception to continue bubbling up (and assuming there are no other exception handlers) and causing the process to abort with an unhandled exception:

  ```
  throw;
  ```
- Shutdown explicitly using [`Environment.Exit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit.aspx)

  ```
  Environment.Exit(-1);
  ```
- Another option is [Application.Shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597013.aspx):

  ```
  Application.Current.Shutdown();
  ```

Rethrowing will show an error to the user. The other two options will not.

Comment: Is one preferred over the other, I also saw some code that was something like Application.ShutDown (I don't think it was exactly this...)

Comment: It was this `Application.Current.Shutdown();`

Comment: Can you elaborate on why `throw` does not allow the app ton continue?

Comment: In my case, NLog displays a message box to the user, so I guess throw is not necessary here.

Comment: @Xaisoft - Probably. And the error message that comes up is not very nice. `Environment.Exit` is good to give the calling process (if scripting the application, for example) an exit code, which could indicate the type of error.

Comment: Yes I noticed, thanks for the help.

Comment: I noticed you can't call `Application.Current.Shutdown()` from a class library, so I guess Environment.Exist is sufficient in this case?